# How do I restrict GraphQL access with Basic Auth?

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

According to this Gitbook (near the bottom), its possible to require GraphQL query authentication with Drupal Core's Basic Auth module. This allows GraphQL to authenticate against a user stored in the Drupal DB.

https://drupal-graphql.gitbook.io/graphql/authentication/authentication

I created an event subscriber that adds the Basic Auth option to the route like this:

```
use Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;

class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('graphql.query.default:default')) {
      $route->setOptions(['_auth' => ['basic_auth']]);
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I make a curl request without an Authorization header it still goes through:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"   --data '{"query":"{fileById(id: \"33\") {changed}}","variables":null,"operationName":null}' http://MYLOCALHOST/graphql
```

Response:

```
{"data":{"fileById":{"changed":1572374455}}}
```

I did enable my custom module with the RouteSubscriber information above and also the Basic Auth module. When I visit the `/graphql` Drupal path in a browser, access is denied but when I make the CURL request it goes through. I was hoping to restrict CURL access as well.

Here is the Drupal 8 documentation on Basic Auth:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/basic_auth/overview

I am using v3 of the Drupal 8 GraphQL module.

Answer (score 2):

I got it!

I needed to add

```
$route->setRequirements(['_user_is_logged_in' => 'TRUE']);
```

...And then do the curl request with the username and password.